# using Google GmailAPI send mail not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need help. Program WebApplication Code C# Asp.Net

First ,I've implemented a way to put a URI in Google OAuth 2 authorization.
Download the Json file for the program to read the file and generate the token.

[image]
[image]

Error

> Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=879100301665-3hpkd1h812d5eejji8o4mku3c2ci3rcs.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A63526%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.send" for authorization. See inner exception for details.

Second , I used to put values ​​in Programs by assigning **Client ID** and **Client secret** in Google OAuth 2 authorization.

[image]

Error
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not images of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with what you are doing.

First being that you have created what appears to be a web application credentials on Google cloud console.  However the code you are using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is intended for use with installed applications only.    This is why you are getting the error you are getting.

The code for creating an asp .net core web app is as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = {YOUR_CLIENT_ID};
            options.ClientSecret = {YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET};
        });
}
```

The second issue you are having is that the redirect uri you are adding is not a valid URL it needs to be https:// at the very least you are missing the //.  As well as the fact that the client library will be sending the request using /signin-google

So a proper redirect uri should be more like this.

```
https://localhost:5001/signin-google
```

I have a YouTube video which shows [How to get a Google users profile information, with C#.](https://youtu.be/aqjglbdFGPk)  with a companion blog post [Asp .net core 3 and Google login](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)  both should work fine with .net 5 as well.